# Is there a difference between pulling the plug and holding power for 5 seconds on a PC?

Tags: power

This is in the context of data not being flushed from the disk cache during a power interruption. If I power down a PC by holding the power button, will any disk caches flush themselves since there is still power? Or does ACPI make it function as if the power was immediately cut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holding the power button forces a main supply cutoff, but leaves standby power on. Since drives do not have access to standby power, the result is the same.